# 今日本語習ってるんですが、この質問どうやって答えるん？

Tags: expressions

2回見るのは当然やろ？？

My native language is English and I want to agree with the person but I'm not sure how. The person is my friend and I want to know how to agree with a person when talking as a friend. This isn't a formal conversation.

Comment: Are you learning Kansai-ben or another dialect, by any chance? I see やろ here, but the main reason I ask is that you ended your own question with ん.

Comment: Please edit the title, it is unclear. And add more information to the question. There are lots of ways to agree with someone, それな、同感 etc. but we cannot answer you without any detail

Answer (score 1):

Oh, fascinating question, because there are so many ways to communicate your acknowledgement, just like there are so many in English, too. It does reflect the personality of the speaker somewhat, but to be honest, I don't know which form conveys what impression, why, or if that impression is universally held.

I'm not native to the dialect you are learning, but just to name a few,

- うん
- そうそう
- だよね
- あー

I almost think what you say doesn't matter too much, it's the whole combination of what you say, your facial and body expression that deliver the message. For example, you can probably say 「なに言うてんの」 (what are you saying?) with sufficient smile and giggling, and that will be received as an agreement, not as an objection.

You have a friend who speaks Japanese that you seem to be conversing, so there should be a plenty of opportunities for you to watch them react positively like this. See how they are doing it, copy some of them, and see how others react when you do it. I think you'll soon find your own voice.